# Magento how to add new select box in product view toolbar section without change .phtml file

Tags: magento-1.9, layout, magento-community, toolbar, grid-layout

Hi i have a toolbar like below image.[image]

I want to add new `"Show"` select box like below image.

[image]

For this i have added select box code directly into the `toolbar.phtml`  file. But I don't like to update any existing phtml code. I plan to develop like a extension. So Is any way to do this via layout?

Please give me any suggestion to how to achieve this like extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My Answer is below

```
<catalog_category_layered translate="label">
        <reference name="product_list">
            <block type="catalog/product_list_toolbar" name="product_list_toolbar" template="customcatalog/mytoolbar.phtml"/>
        </reference>
 </catalog_category_layered>
```

I added this line into my layout file. It will called mytoolbar.phtml file instead of catalog product toolbar.phtml

I copied all the codes from toolbar.phtml file into mytoolbar.phtml and added my selectbox code. It is working fine.

Comment: Please let me know is this good way or not.